# Type EAL.STATUS_DATE is not a defined system type

Tags: sql

All, I'm trying to shorting my date and time data.  Here is the current code...

**ISNULL(EAL.STATUS_DATE,'01/01/1960') AS STATUS_DATE**

Result...
*2016-04-18 00:00:00.000*

and I want it to returns only 2016-04-18
I tried this code **ISNULL(CONVERT(EAL.STATUS_DATE,'01/01/1960'),110) AS STATUS_DATE**  but got this error  T*ype EAL.STATUS_DATE is not a defined system type.*

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the two functions mixed together incorrectly. the convert belongs only around the datetime field. then you do the isnull on the outside of that. You also have the syntax of convert wrong.

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(date,EAL.STATUS_DATE,110), '01/01/1960')
```

Comment: I see it now.  Thank you very much